# python in network, if several packets arrive at same time, what does socket do

Tags: python, sockets, networking

in python, nework,

Server:

while 1:

```
    message, address = socket.recvfrom(2048)    # @1
    do soemthing here   # @2
```

if two packets arrive at literally same time, or you can assume that when secnod packet arrives, program is still at @2 dealing with first packet, and it does not finished, so it is not at @1 waiting.

Here is my assumption, socket(not the code you write) can buffer certain amount of data, and when program finished @2 for packet 1, and go back @1, the buffer will pass buffered data to it no matter UDP or TCP.

Am i correct or something is not exactly same

Any help is much appreciated.
thanks advance

Comment: "_if two packets arrive at literally same time_" Frames arrive serially on an interface, so packets (the payload of frames) cannot arrive "_literally same time_."

Comment: thanks for replying, the key point is that if program(python) is still dealing with first packet, and second packet arrives, what would happen, discard second packet? or socket itself buffer second packet?

Comment: The transport protocol keeps it until the application asks for it.

Comment: so, the socket buffers it until program asks? Is it both working for UDP and TCP